# Appropriate statistical test evaluating difference in proportions between two groups over multiple time points

Tags: time-series, anova, repeated-measures, proportion, prevalence

Over the course of a year, I took samples from dogs and their beds and looked for the type of bacteria in the bed and in the dog every month. I did not get samples from the same dogs or the same beds at each month.

When grouped together, I see that the prevalence of bacteria X is significantly higher among dogs than it is in beds. When I plot this over time, it similarly shows that at each time point, the prevalence of bacteria X is significantly higher among dogs that their beds at each time point.

I want to use something like a repeated measures ANOVA, however, since the same dogs and the same beds were not sampled, it would not be a within-subject comparison. What would be the alternative test for my data?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, do you have several observations per dog? (at least for some dogs?). Also, do each dog only have one bed or can there be several beds per dog?

Comment: Did not have several observations per dog. Several beds per dog.

Comment: And is you research question whether the level of bacteria is higher in dogs or beds?

Comment: Yes. When I plot it out, it looks quite obvious that the bacteria levels are higher in dogs than beds at all 12 timepoints. When all data is grouped together (agnostic of timepoint), it shows that. But I was wondering if there is a better test to look at it? The last ditch option would be 12 separate T-tests for each timepoint.

Comment: OK, wow, this is actually a super interesting question but unfortunately out of my league, I hope you get an answer from someone who knows. I see 3 complexities here: 1) observations from dogs and their beds are not independent, 2) you don't have measures from all beds or all dogs at all time points and 3) you have more data points from beds than from dogs. I would probably forget about time and average across beds (within dog), but that leaves the interdependence between dog and its beds. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!